# Layover in Mexico, clear customs on first port of entry?

Tags: airports, airport-security, mexico

On an international flight (to Mexico) with a layover in Mexico DF, do I have to clear Mexican customs and redo security in DF before taking the connection like we do in Canada and the US ?
Is there an exit security check before leaving the airport and entering the city ?

I'm trying to find out how much time I need between/before flights. I'm flying from Canada in case it's relevant.

Comment: A clarification, is your final destination in Mexico, or in another country?

Comment: @Flimzy it's in Mexico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  When you land in DF, you will be required to clear immigration and customs with all of your luggage, then re-check any checked bags, and re-clear security. I have done this before, and my girlfriend just did it last week (LHR -> MEX -> GDL).

When things are running smoothly, it shouldn't take more than an hour to do all of that. But if you have checked luggage, and there is a delay in unloading the luggage, for instance, or it's a particularly busy time of day, it make take longer.

It's always better to plan on the side of too much time than too little, IMO. I would want at *least* 2 hours between flights, and would feel more comfortable with 3.  More than 4 and you'll just be killing time (although I have learned not to mind that, if I carry a good book).

Also keep in mind that MEX is a large airport, and depending on where your arrival and departure gates are located, you may spend as much as 20-30 minutes just walking between gates.